# Learning DRF: Serialize models in a group

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to both Django and DRF. I need to expose the following JSON via GET, but I seem to be having trouble getting each class to be a part of classes []. I belive I can use StringRelatedField for this, but the examples I have found don't seem to click with me. Thanks in advance!

expected output

```
{
   "classes":[
      {
         "id":24,
         "name":"Math 101",
         "starts_on":"2016-08-09",
         "ends_on":"2016-08-14",
         "entries_url":"https://example.com/classes/24/classes.json"
      },
      {
         "id":23,
         "name":"English 101",
         "starts_on":"2016-07-28",
         "ends_on":"2016-07-30",
         "entries_url":"https://example.com/classes/23/classes.json"
      }
  ]
}
```

Here's what I've cobbled together. "nr" is just a throwaway variable as I don't actually want any data besides what comes from class.

model.py

```
class Class(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    starts_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    ends_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    entries_url = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)

class Classes(models.Model):
    nr = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

serializers.py

```
class ClassesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Classes
        fields = ('classes')
```

Comment: What do your models look like?

Comment: What do you expect as output?

Comment: updated poorly thought out model/serializer. Evans: The output is what I first posted (JSON)

Comment: @CareFree you should be careful shadowing built-in Python reserved words. I would reconsider calling it `Class` so that you don't accidentally shadow `class`.

Comment: good point. Thanks.

Comment: @CareFree also, make sure that singleton tuples have a comma in them: `fields = ('classes', )`.

Answer (score 3):

Your database needs to keep a relation between your tables. You can use a [foreign key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) here:

```
class Class(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    starts_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    ends_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    entries_url = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    related_classes = models.ForeignKey('Classes', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='classes')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)

class Classes(models.Model):
    nr = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Then, your serializer becomes:

```
class ClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = Class
         fields = ['__all__']

class ClassesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    classes = ClassSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Classes
        fields = ('classes',)
```

Also, I strongly discourage you to use `class` for your variables, since it clashes with the `class` keyword of Python.

Comment: I guess I should have let you know that I am also using a POST operation to populate the DB. Your above code looks very promising, however of course I made a new DB and when I try to add data to it, I get "related_classes": [
        "This field is required." If I submit anything in that field, it doesn't recognize the PK

Comment: You have to serialize that field using a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`. Have a look at the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) to get started on that.